# "As I said before" vs "before which as I said"

Tags: prepositions

I read this from the book Oxford Grammar that the preposotion **before** doesn't normally come at the end.

Example:

> There's a meeting at twelve, **before** which we need to talk to
> Lonnie. (NOT ... *which we need to talk to Lonnie before*)

The example above makes me think, what about the phrase that is usually used i.e. *As I said before*? Will it be grammatically correct should it be written as *Before which as I said*?

Comment: [Is it ok to use 'before' at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/160966/288445)

Comment: @41686d6564 it's different. My main discussion here js preposition. I couldn't find the information I need in that link. Thanks, however, for the link.

Comment: I'm not sure I get how it's different. How is [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/160970/288445) (or [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/160969/288445)) any different from the answer you just accepted?

Comment: "Before which as I said" is referring to something else, in the way that you said before, like "before this other thing, like I said before".  You would only use it like "The main event is at 9, before which, as I said, there will be a number of opening acts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'As I said before' is correct. Here before has the generic sense of 'earlier than now', rather than the specific sense of 'before another event'.